# cannot play mp3 file. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

When I press the play button, I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.`
I have tried everything and cannot find the issue.
HTML:

```
<section class="tape">
  
        <audio src="audio/forest-lullaby-110624.mp3"  crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
        
        
  <!--      type="audio/mpeg" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3" -->
  
        <button data-playing="false" class="tape-controls-play" role="switch" aria-checked="false">
          <span>Play/Pause</span>
        </button>
      </section>
      
    </div><!-- boombox-body -->
  </div>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
```

script2.js:

```
// for cross browser
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

// load some sound
const audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
const track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

const playButton = document.querySelector('.tape-controls-play');

// play pause audio
playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
  if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
    audioCtx.resume();
  }
  
  if (this.dataset.playing === 'false') {
    audioElement.play();
    this.dataset.playing = 'true';
  // if track is playing pause it
  } else if (this.dataset.playing === 'true') {
    audioElement.pause();
    this.dataset.playing = 'false';
  }
```

Original source code can be found at https://codepen.io/Rumyra/pen/qyMzqN/